# AWS Create AMI from custom SLES 15 appliance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I am creating a custom SLES 15 SP1 appliance to use as a base for some software specifically designed for SLES 15. I am using KIWI-ng to do this so I can end up with any kind of image file needed (ISO, VMDK, OVF, OVA, etc..).

I need to get this custom appliance into AWS but I am having difficulties. I am aware that AWS [does not officially support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmie_prereqs.html#vmimport-operating-systems) importing this OS and kernel but surely there is some way to get it in there because AWS has a SLES 15 AMI in their marketplace. I cannot use the marketplace option because of package differences and I need to be able to export the AMI.

---

[VM import/export](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/) doesn't work for my case.

I get a kernel version unsupported error during import. 
4.12.14-197.37-default is the kernel version my appliance ends up with.

---

Is there any way to get this appliance into AWS?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this. I am also evaluating such a thing but stuck with the unsupported kernel version.